# NPM package.json dependencies and their executables in local vs global

Tags: node.js, npm

I think `npm install|update` works when requiring dependencies in source files, but when I want to run an executable, like `nodemon`, it doesn't appear to work. Is it trying to look for the file globally? How can I make these commands look in `node_modules` first?

---

I have a Cakefile that starts the dev server with `nodemon`. For example:

```
# **`procExec(procName)`**
# returns the path to executable in `node_`
procExec = (procName) -> 
    console.log "./node_modules/" + procName + "/bin/" + procName
    "./node_modules/.bin/" + procName

# **`cake startdev`**
# Starts the server with `nodemon`
# Watch and compile `.coffee` and `.styl` files in `/client`

task "startdev", "Starts server with nodemon and watch files for changes", ->
    # start nodemon server
    nodemon = spawn procExec("nodemon"), ["server.coffee"]
    processOutput nodemon

    # watch and compile CoffeeScript
    coffee = spawn procExec("coffee"), ["-o", "public/js/app", "-cw", "client/coffee"]
    processOutput coffee

    # watch and compile Stylus
    stylus = spawn procExec("stylus"), ["client/stylus", "-l", "-w", "-o", "public/css/app"]
    processOutput stylus
```

It works but with a few minor problems:

- `npm install|update` doesn't seem to install `nodemon`. I think it tries to install globally and fails. I manually did a `npm install nodemon` separately. Why is this? And how can I tell `nodemon` to install anyway?
- Does `"./node_modules/.bin/" + procName` always resolve to the correct executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few questions in here, so I'll try and keep them separated.

> npm install|update doesn't seem to install nodemon. I think it tries to install globally and fails. I manually did a npm install nodemon separately. Why is this? And how can I tell nodemon to install anyway?

Did you see a warning about "prefer global install"? If that's the case it was just a warning and it would've been installed anyways. If it was a different error please include the output.

> Does "./node_modules/.bin/" + procName always resolve to the correct executable?

Yes, any scripts listed in the package.json files of your dependencies will be installed to this folder. However, I much prefer using the `npm bin` command to always get the correct path.

If you are spawning processes from node, you can also `require('npm')` and modify `process.env.PATH` to get the correct `node_modules/.bin` in place. E.g. at the top of your Cakefile:

```
npm = require 'npm'
npm.load (err) -> throw err # If config fails to load, bail out early
process.env.PATH = npm.bin + ":" + process.env.PATH
# Now you no longer need to use procExec in your tasks
```

*disclaimer* I don't know if modifying PATH like that will work on windows.

Comment: Wheres the code in the `npm = require ...` part of the answer thats spawning the process?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this for a while. You would still use `spawn` as before, but without the procExec helper.